# How to change instance variables inside anonymous class

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, instance-variables, anonymous-class

I have a class `UserName` which has been created for the purpose of returning the userName when provided with userID. The problem is that I can't change the instance variable `userName` inside the anonymous class `ValueEventListener`. The `Log.i()` function inside the anonymous class successfully prints the correct userName but while returning the variable through `getUserName()` function it returns empty string variable. How can I change such **instance variables** inside any **anonymous classes** ?

```
public class UserName {
    String userName;
    public UserName(String userID){
        DatabaseReference dbRefUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        Query queryGetUserName = dbRefUsers.orderByChild("userID").equalTo(userID);
        queryGetUserName.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshotCurrent: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        User userCurrent = dataSnapshotCurrent.getValue(User.class);
                        userName = userCurrent.getName();
                        Log.i("userName",userName);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks to be a possible [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) type question as I don't think that the problem is with your not being able to change userName since instance variables *can* be changed within inner classes, anonymous or otherwise, and your code looks to be doing this, but perhaps the problem here is your calling `getUserName()` **before** it has been changed since it is changed within a call-back method. Please post more information about how you're using this code and when exactly you call `getUserName()`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I am using this code in my activities as `userName = new UserName(userID).getUserName();`

Comment: And as I explained, that is why your code is not working. The user name is changed in a ***call-back*** method, meaning it does not happen immediately and may not happen at all, only if the event that triggers the call-back occurs. You had best read up on call-back methods since you appear to not understand how they work and how this has bearing on your code.

Comment: Read on what triggers the FireBase database to call the `onDataChange(...)` method. ***This*** is when your call-back method is fired.

Comment: So how can I create a class which if I call in my activities would return me correct userName when it is provided with appropriate userID ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code should work, if you call `getUserName` **AFTER** you call your `onDataChange` method.

Here is an example illustrating that it works using a `JButton` and an `ActionListener`

```
public class UserName {
    private String userName;
    private JButton button = new JButton();

    public UserName() {
        button.addActionListener(e -> userName = "bob");
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
}
```

If I do

```
UserName userName = new UserName();
System.out.println(userName.getUserName());
```

It prints null.

But if I do

```
UserName userName = new UserName();
userName.getButton().doClick();
System.out.println(userName.getUserName());
```

Then it prints "bob"

So your issue can be that:

- you call `getUserName` before `onDataChange`,
- or your `onDataChange` method does not set the value because it does not go into the `if` statement or that your `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` is empty,
- or even that the userName of the user in the last child is an empty String (Note that your code always returns the userName on the last child, is that inteded?)

Comment: The retrieving of data is not a problem as when I am using `Log.i("userName",userName);` inside the `ValueEventListener`it successfully prints the right userName but when when I called `getUserName()` function it returns empty String variable. I use this code in my activities as `userName = new UserName(userID).getUserName();` and I am assuming that since I am calling the `UserName()` constructor first and then the `getUserName()` function I should get the correct userName which I am able to print through `Log.i()` function.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't aware about the working of call-back methods.  I couldn't figure that the problem with my code was due to the sequence in which the code is being executed. Thanks for your help and time.